# Program crashes after adding a Border to a Textblock

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, border

I have a little problem. I am enabling the user to choose the size of a textblock in which he is able to display text by doing some other stuff.
My problem here is that I have to add a border to the textblock to show the user how big it became.
When I applied the following code, my program just crashes in that scenario:

```
                //create a TextBlock at desired position

                TextBlock tmpTextBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Width = 166,
                    Height = Math.Max(tmpY1, tmpY2) - Math.Min(tmpY1, tmpY2),
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, Math.Min(tmpY1, tmpY2) - 50, 0, (int)WeekGrid.ActualHeight - Math.Max(tmpY1, tmpY2)),             
                    Text = "Type stuff here"
                };

                tmpTextBlock.Holding += tmpTextBox_Holding;
                tmpTextBlock.RightTapped += tmpTextBox_RightTapped;

                WeekGrid.Children.Add(tmpTextBlock);
                Grid.SetRow(tmpTextBlock, 1);


                //add the border - these lines produce the problem

                Border border = new Border
                {
                    Child = tmpTextBlock,
                    Background = this.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                    BorderBrush = this.Resources["ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                };
```

The Exception that follows is an argument exception:

Value does not fall within the expected range.

EDIT

Whoops I've solved that problem. I had to remove adding the Textblock into the grid.
The problem I have now is that the border appears around the grid - not around the textblock!

The following code made that possible:

```
                Border border = new Border
                {
                    Child = tmpTextBlock,
                    Background = this.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                    BorderBrush = this.Resources["ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                    Padding = new Thickness(24)
                };

                WeekGrid.Children.Add(border);
                Grid.SetRow(border, 1);
```

EDIT 2

Problem solved again.
I of course had to remove the margin setting of the textblock!

Thank you very much!

Greetings,
FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the exception?

clearly there is an error in your code here:

```
            WeekGrid.Children.Add(tmpTextBlock);
            Grid.SetRow(tmpTextBlock, 1);

            //add the border - these lines produce the problem

            Border border = new Border
            {
                Child = tmpTextBlock,
                Background = this.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                BorderBrush = this.Resources["ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
            };
```

The component `Border` it is like a "container", which accepts a single element, you should switch to:

```
         Border border = new Border
            {
                Child = tmpTextBlock,
                Background = this.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                BorderBrush = this.Resources["ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
            };

            WeekGrid.Children.Add(border);
            Grid.SetRow(border, 1);
```

You should also check if the resources are "available" for your access.

Comment: Hey. Thanks I've tried your idea but it still does not work properly and throws out the same exception. I've also added the exception into my post.

Comment: You could you check the values of the Height and Margin? There is a chance the problem will not be found in these lines?

Comment: The problem I had is solved now. I had to remove adding the textblock into the grid and add the border instead. Still another one occurred. I've added further information in my post.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot :) I'd like your comment but I have too few reputation...

Comment: you're welcome, if the issue is resolved, you could mark as an answer.